# Python: why I can import a package in python but not in jupyter?

Tags: python, jupyter

I installed a pacakge called `mgwr`

```
pip3 install mgwr
```

If I do

```
python3
Python 3.6.8 (v3.6.8:3c6b436a57, Dec 24 2018, 02:10:22) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5666) (dot 3)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

>>> import mgwr
```

it works fine.

However, if I try

```
jupyter notebook
```

and I call it from the notebook it returns

```
ImportError: No module named mgwr
```

Comment: are they running in the same environment?

Comment: @crash  I think no. In fact if I do from  `print(python_version())` in the notebook it returns `2.7.15` even if I need python3. However the kernel says python3

Comment: I suggest you to create a virtual environment and add that to jupyter notebook, I'll try to post a question with how I'd do that, give me 2 mins. Are you using anaconda?

Comment: No, I am not using anaconda

Answer (score 0):

It's probably due to the fact that they're not running on the same environment. I've generally been successful in this general procedure:

**1.** Create a virtual environment

```
$ pip install virtualenv
$ cd project_folder
$ virtualenv my_venv
```

This will create the `my_venv` environment. Activate it with `source my_venv/bin/activate` and install the desired packages.

**2.** Add the virtual environment just created to jupyter notebook with

```
$ pip install ipykernel
$ ipython kernel install --user --name=my_venv
```

Now when you open your jupyter notebook and create a new notebook you should see the `my_venv` kernel as well.

Comment: you sure you have activated the virtual env, installed the package there and then created the jupyter notebook with the same kernel? Does this happen with all the packages or just one?